# Wildfly 8 - Erro no debug

Tags: wildfly

Estou tentando debugar minha action (Eclipse Mars, Wildfly 8, Struts 2 e java 8), inicio o servidor na opção Debug, mas ao pressionar F6 ou clicar no ícone para processar a partir de um determinado ponto o foco passa para linhas que não tem código.  Já tentei:

- Clean do projeto
- Clean do Servidor
- Full Publish

No menu Windows->Preferences, procurei alguma configuração para debug, mas não encontrei.

Answer (score 0):

A solução é simples, conversando com um amigo, conseguimos identificar o problema.  Perda no sincronismo do código.  Para solucionar o problema, basta atualizar o projeto, clique no projeto com o botão direito do mouse e em seguida no Refresh. Depois é só executar o clean do projeto e iniciar o servidor em modo debug.